# How long does it take for a great works project to start building?

Tags: simcity-2013

How long do you have to wait until the Great Works Project can start to be built?

I already paid the §1,000,000 and am still waiting for the bureaucratic paperwork to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took about 10 to 15 real time minutes for me. I don't know if the ingame speed has anything to do with it. Just be patient.

Comment: Servers are a bit buggy for some people, so time varies. But yeah, be patient. Same with resources and power/water supplied to Great Work.

Comment: I can herby confirm what you wrote Simbabque! Thanks for the answer :)